# Make a loop not as a path

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

How can I get a node with an edge where it loops to the same node, but as an edge not as a path (i.e without an arrow}

This is my current code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   [node distance = 20mm and 20mm,
   main/.style = {draw, circle}] 
   
   every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize}
   
    \node[main] ({9})                                       {$v_1$}; 
    \node[main] ({10}) [below right of = {9}]               {$v_2$};
    \node[main] ({11}) [below of = {10}]                    {$v_3$};
    \node[main] ({13}) [below left of = {9}]                {$v_4$};
    \node[main] ({12}) [below of = {13}]                    {$v_5$};
    
    \draw ({9}) edge[""] ({10});
    \draw ({10}) edge[""] ({11});
    \draw ({11}) edge[""] ({12});
    \draw ({12}) edge[""] ({13});
    \draw ({9}) edge[""] ({13});
    \draw ({9}) edge[""] ({11});
    \draw ({9}) edge[""] ({12});
    \draw ({10}) edge[""] ({12});
    \draw ({10}) edge[""] ({13});
    \draw ({11}) edge[""] ({13});
    \draw ({1}) edge [loop above] [""] (1);
```

Trying to make a penatope graph with a loop on the top vertex, but with this code the loop is a path(has an arrow}

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please make your code compilable so that people can help you.

Comment: An `edge` gets drawn by default. You will need options `draw=none` or `path only` for your edge or use use `\path` and `to` instead of `\draw` and `edge`. That said, your code is not only incomplete it is also full of errors. The nodes have now text. `;` are missing. The `every edge quotes` style is not inside the pictures options or `\tikzset`.